# Extension private field in java

Tags: java

I read the Spring Data source and meet a question：
JdbcTemplate has a method:

```
public void setDataSource(@Nullable DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
```

and I find that this.dataSource is from it`s father class JdbcAccessor.declearing as follow

```
private DataSource dataSource;
```

my question is: why extension class JdbcTemplate can access its father class`s private field?
I try to use it as follow and find IDE show its wrong

```
public abstract class A {
    @Nullable
    private Integer a;
}

public class B extends A {

    public void setA(@Nullable Integer a) {
        this.a = a;    <-- Wrong
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find a `setDataSource()` method in [JdbcTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java) - the method is actually in [JdbcAccessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/cf8c36adf34e4faacf69415c6e04e8f418da2074/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcAccessor.java#L74) and therefore correct

Comment: @ThomasKläger I made a serious mistake,this method is in jdbcAccessor,thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can not. Most likely you used some sort of decompiler which couldn't properly decompile it. The actual code is like this in [JDBCTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java)

```
public JdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

And setDatasource method is in [JDBCAccessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/cf8c36adf34e4faacf69415c6e04e8f418da2074/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/support/JdbcAccessor.java#L42).

Comment: Yes,this method is in JDBCAccessor,I made a serious mistake,thank you~

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access private properties in another class. So you need to add a setter method to add values to private properties.

```
public abstract class A {
    @Nullable
    private Integer a;

    public void setValue(Integer a){
       this.a=a;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public void setA(@Nullable Integer a) {
       this.setValue(a);
    }
}
```